# Regex Replace gives different output according to compiler

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

[DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/BLiWBiY3F)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string bstr = "111111111111111111111111111111111111111110";
    
    std::regex re(".{6}");
    bstr = std::regex_replace(bstr, re, "|$00");

    std::cout << "bstr: " << bstr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why when I compile the same code using `visual studio 2022` i get a different value stored on `bstr` after running the `regex_replace` function?

[image]

Comment: It seems that [ECMAScript standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) doesn't define `$00` as the whole match, it only defines `$nn` for values bigger than `0`. Try with `"|$&"` to make it conformant and see if it fixes the problem (don't have Visual Studio on hand, so I can't check myself before posting an answer).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you should post that as an answer

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `"|$&"` output: `bstr: |111111|111111|111111|111111|111111|111111|111110` in  Visual  Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Use `$&` as a reference to whole match. In this case the correct format string is:

```
    bstr = std::regex_replace(bstr, re, "|$&");
```

---

Long answer: Well, this is a rare case where MSVC is right and gcc and clang are (technically) buggy.

C++ default regex flavour is based on [ECMAScript](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) standard. This standard defines `$n` and `$nn` as backreference to a capture group number `n` or `nn`, but neither of them allows `0` as valid group number. An invalid substitution should be left as is (i.e. treated like any other plain text).

This is what MSVC is doing. It recognizes that `$00` substitution is invalid per standard and treats it as plain text. gcc and clang on the other hand made it work like `std::regex_match` and treat group number `0` as the whole match. A reasonable assumption, but technically incorrect by standard.

This can be confirmed also with regex101: [`|$00` is replaced](https://regex101.com/r/wjZYwC/1) with just that text, [`|$&` is replaced](https://regex101.com/r/EYs54Y/1) with the match.